How do I convert Numpy code to Torch code?
I want to convert this code from pyroomacoustics to pytorch. And for the life of me, I am unable to do so. I cant get rid of this error for when torch.where() returns an empty list.
def measure_rt60(h, fs=1, decay_db=60):
  """
  Analyze the RT60 of an impulse response

  Parameters
  ----------
  h: array_likeThe impulse response.
  fs: float or int, optional The sampling frequency of h (default 
  to 1, i.e., samples).
  decay_db: float or int, optional
  The decay in decibels for which we actually estimate the time. 
  """

  h = np.array(h)
  fs = float(fs)

  # The power of the impulse response in dB
  power = h**2
  energy = np.cumsum(power[::-1])[::-1]  # Integration according to Schroeder

  # remove the possibly all zero tail
  i_nz = np.max(np.where(energy > 0)[0])
  energy = energy[:i_nz]
  energy_db = 10 * np.log10(energy)
  energy_db -= energy_db[0]

  # -5 dB headroom
  i_5db = np.min(np.where(-5 - energy_db > 0)[0])
  e_5db = energy_db[i_5db]
  t_5db = i_5db / fs

  # after decay
  i_decay = np.min(np.where(-5 - decay_db - energy_db > 0)[0])
  t_decay = i_decay / fs

  # compute the decay time
  decay_time = t_decay - t_5db
  est_rt60 = (60 / decay_db) * decay_time

return est_rt60

Here is what I have so far. The issue is in the calculated of i_decay where I get this error:
RuntimeError: min(): Expected reduction dim to be specified for input.numel() == 0. Specify the reduction dim with the 'dim' argument.
def measure_rt60_torch(h, fs=1, decay_db=60):
   fs = float(fs)
   decay_db = float(decay_db)

   power = h**2
   energy = torch.cumsum(power.flip(-1), -1).flip(-1) 
   i_nz = torch.max(torch.nonzero(energy > 0)[-1])
   energy = energy[:i_nz]
   energy_db = 10 * torch.log10(energy)
   energy_db_adjusted = energy_db.clone()  
   energy_db_adjusted -= energy_db[0]



   i_5db = torch.min(torch.nonzero(torch.tensor(-5.) -energy_db_adjusted > torch.tensor(0.), as_tuple=True)[0])
   e_5db = energy_db_adjusted[i_5db]
   t_5db = i_5db / fs


   i_decay = torch.min(torch.nonzero(torch.tensor(-5.) - 
   torch.tensor(decay_db) - energy_db_adjusted > torch.tensor(0.), as_tuple=True)[0])
   t_decay = i_decay / fs

   decay_time = t_decay - t_5db
   est_rt60 = (60 / decay_db) * decay_time

   return est_rt60.item()


def measure_rtX(x, fs=48000, decay_db=60):
"""
get reverberation time for x dB (time for energy decay by x dB)
:param x: IR
:param fs: sampling frequency
:param decay_db: energy decay in dB
:return: idx in x where the energy decays by decay_db
"""

  wrapper_list = []
  iteration=0
  for batch_idx in range(x.size(0)):
      batch_x = x[batch_idx]
      print(iteration,batch_x.size())
      iteration+=1
      rtX = -1
      while rtX == -1:
          try:
              rtX = measure_rt60_torch(batch_x, fs, decay_db)
          except ValueError:
              if decay_db > 10:
                  decay_db -= 10
              else:
                  rtX = batch_x.size(0) / fs
      wrapper_list.append(rtX)
  return wrapper_list




x_tensor = torch.randn(32, 96000)
x_tensor = x_tensor.float()
print(x_tensor.size())
list_wrapper = measure_rtX(x_tensor, fs=48000)


I believe the equivalent of the single-argument form of np.where() would be torch.nonzero(..., as_tuple=True).


Can you provide an example of how to call this code, which works in NumPy, but fails when converted to torch? 2) Can you fix the indentation?


@NickODell I have added all the relevant code and fixed the indentation.

Did you compare the docs for where in the two packages?  np.where suggests using nonzero instead.

@hpaulj I have also tried the implementation with nonzero instead of where but I encounter the same error in both cases.

Then look at the nonzero result itsel (the tuple), and if necessary yhe condition argument the passvit.  In other wirfds, basic debugging steps of isolating the problem.  But why the min in the first place?  I don't know the relevant array dimensions, or the possibilty of no ?nonzero match.

@hpaulj I have tried to debug this myself. The possibility of an empty tuple is none. I test out the same code with the numpy version and get positive results. Which is why I am stuck. I could add conditions to only check if the torch.nonzero returns a non-empty tuple but because in my use case, I am certain that this will not be the case, I want to debug this issue and come up with a valid implementation.
